# How can I understand the content of 'Mifare classic 1k'?

Tags: hex, nfc, mifare

I am trying to understand what data is inside this tageta. I tried to pass it to ASCII but rare characters come out.

> **+Sector: 0**
>   53E04E2DD00804006263646566676869
>   00006166280000000000000000000026
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A0000000000078778869B00000000000
>
> **+Sector: 1**
>   F852340000000000000000000000001A
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A0100000000078778869B01000000000
>
> **+Sector: 2**
>   2020202020202020202020202020206B
>   2020202020202020202020202020206B
>   2020202020202020202020202020206B
>   A0200000000078778869B02000000000
>
> **+Sector: 3**
>   BC036087E80102000000000000000020
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A0300000000078778869B03000000000
>
> **+Sector: 4**
>   04C4220000888EA96E4DA4781111C9D8
>   04C4220000888EA96E4DA4781111C9D8
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A040000000007B478869B04000000000
>
> **+Sector: 5**
>   BC542B0000000000FF6909000000002B
>   0100008088270E041CE0566EB00700A2
>   0100008088270E041CE0566EB00700A2
>   A050000000007E178869B05000000000
>
> **+Sector: 6**
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A060000000007E178869B06000000000
>
> **+Sector: 7**
>   FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF1CE31C73
>   FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFF1DE21DAC
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A0700000000048778B69B07000000000
>
> **+Sector: 8**
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A0800000000078778869B08000000000
>
> **+Sector: 9**
>   FEA30411A812F505548702A0006C1336
>   FEA30411A812F505548702B0107122A2
>   FEA30411A812F505548702C0104117E1
>   A0900000000078778869B09000000000
>
> **+Sector: 10**
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A1000000000078778869B10000000000
>
> **+Sector: 11**
>   A03A80404000B25C7D27DE0E11AB19DD
>   A11A80404012AA5B13299E6C11CB45F2
>   A03A80404020B7DB6DE99E6C11EEC4D4
>   A110000000007F078869B11000000000
>
> **+Sector: 12**
>   A11A80402002B25C7D27DE21110E75D1
>   A03A80404000B25C7D279E0E11CE19C8
>   A11A80404062AA5B13299EA711EE19D1
>   A120000000007F078869B12000000000
>
> **+Sector: 13**
>   A05A00814080375E52E95E00110F354C
>   A11A00812092B1DCB127DE28112F0978
>   A03A80404020B7DB6DE99E6C11F1C49B
>   A130000000007F078869B13000000000
>
> **+Sector: 14**
>   A11A80402062AA5B13299E541111C9A1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A1400000000079678869B14000000000
>
> **+Sector: 15**
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   000000000000000000000000000000B1
>   A1500000000078778869B15000000000

I mean like you can turn it into data that you can understand?

Answer (score 2):

The First Sector (0) is the **MAD** where the first block is the 
manufacturecode. Then comes the **MIFARE Application Directory (MAD)**
which says where are the applications stored. The Byte 0 from BLOCK1
is a CRC in your case 0x26 then byte1 is an info byte after that 
there comes the **application id´s (AID´s)** 2 byte per AID in your case
there is in Sector 5 an Application with the AID 2800 and sector 6 an
application with AID 6661 and so on.

The Sector it self is build like:

```
A11A80402002B25C7D27DE21110E75D1 - BLOCK0
A03A80404000B25C7D279E0E11CE19C8 - BLOCK1
A11A80404062AA5B13299EA711EE19D1 - BLOCK2
[    KEYA  ][ AC ]69[   KEYB   ] - SECTORTRAILOR
```

That said your data should be only in SECTOR 5,6,8

For the Data itself there are many way´s to interpret data.

BCD (Binary Coded Decimal)

[image]

Also you can interpret the data as ASCII-Encoded

Further more there is int16, int32, int64 and it´s unsignt equivalent

For your data I try to interpret something. Sector 5 the first block
may build from 4 UInt Numbers which are:

```
BC542B00 ~> 2839740 LSB may be an ID
00000000 ~> 0
FF690900 ~> 616959 LSB another ID
0000002B ~> 43 MSB some kind of version
```

The second Block of Sector 5 starts with a BCD

```
010000808827 ~> 010000808827
```

The software which is interpreting the data should know where to find
it´s data and what todo with it. So mostly the data format is given
by some spec.